# Problem in getting a update statement firing in sqlite for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having a problem in updating data. I use this code for the update.

All this is going well but my data not get updated. what's the problem in this?

I'd like to update the EndDate column value: its data type is DATETIME.

**All thing execute very well but my database table UserJourney's EndDate not getting update What's the problem and how can I solve it?**

```
-(void)journeyEnd
{

    NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];

    sqlite3 *database;


    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    //Create the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Set the required date format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
    //Get the End date
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"this from new map '%@'",journeyid);

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

**this line where i am trying to insert statement after that i remember that i have fire the UPDATE statement** 
        //const char *sqlStatement = "insert into UserJourney(EndDate) VALUES (?) where JourneyID = ''";
//And here I fire the Update statement 
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE UserJourney SET EndDate='%@' WHERE JourneyID='%@'",str,journeyid]; 
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {

            sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
            NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert = nil;

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);    

}
```

Comment: Is JournyID of Text datatype in database?

Comment: There is nothing to bind as you are not using parameterized query, so why are you binding sqlite3_bind_text?

Comment: @jignesh NO JourneyID is VARCHARPRIMARY KEY

Comment: try commenting this line  sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

Comment: No It's not working my firend.Ok you mean to say that in the update statement we can not use the binding line is that right

Comment: yes, binding is only if you have used "?,?" i.e. for parameterized query. if you want to use parameterized query in update statement you can use "UPDATE UserJourney SET EndDate=? WHERE JourneyID=?", then you can use 2 sqlite3_bind_text methods, one for end date and another for journeyid

Comment: Now change the  EndDate 's datatype DATETIME TO TEXT But even it's not working

Comment: Did you debug that str gives you string?

Comment: and did you check in database journeyID which you try to update, exists in database or not?

Comment: @JigneshBrahmkhatri let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1452/discussion-between-shima-and-jignesh-brahmkhatri)

Comment: Yes i debug and check also it 's str give answer proper

Comment: How can i check the JourneyID is in datbase or not and the how can fire the update statement

Comment: you can query select journeyid from table where journeyid='%@', and if it gives any row, you have journeyid in database

Comment: Can I fire the two statement in the same code one for the select statement And for the update statement is that possible to do that

Comment: you need to make another function, which returns boolean, something like [self existsJourney:journeyid];, existsJourney function will check if id exists in database or not...

Comment: And than after what i have do that .Is i have to fire the update statement .If I fire the update statement can it lock the database or not.

Comment: if that function returns true, then you can fire update statement, update statement will be committed to database only after sqlite3_finalize statement.

Comment: I create like this -(BOOL)checkIfAlreadyExists:(NSString*)journey_id{journey_id = journeyid //Because journeyid is my global variable Can it work }

Comment: you need to do it your own way now...

Comment: it show me that there is no journeyid in the database .But when NSlog(@"'%@'",journeyid).It give the proper answer.What was the problem

Comment: if there is no journeyid then How can you update it using journeyid, you can not update journey for which journey id does not exist, and regarding NSLog, its a silly question you are asking, database is different and objective c language is different.....

Comment: But when i put already excite journeyid even it not getting update what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing below method. I did couple of changes. It might help. If not work can you post your database table column datatypes ?

```
-(void)journeyEnd
{

NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];

sqlite3 *database;


NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
//Create the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//Set the required date format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
//Get the End date
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"this from new map '%@'",journeyid);

if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

**this line where i am trying to insert statement after that i remember that i have fire the UPDATE statement** 
    //const char *sqlStatement = "insert into UserJourney(EndDate) VALUES (?) where JourneyID = ''";
//And here I fire the Update statement 
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE UserJourney SET EndDate='%@' WHERE JourneyID='%d'",str,journeyid]; 
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {


    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
        NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        alert = nil;

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);    

}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It's not working Deeps it is the same code which write above nothing changes is done by excepted slitw3_bind_text line delete by you

Comment: I changed %d from %@ for journeyId as well. also I asked for datatype of your tables so I can get more idea. If your date column datatype is datetime then it will not work.

Comment: Than how can solve that this problem You mean to say I have to change my datatype to text or something else. Why you are not write the the binding  statement in this

Comment: Temporary you can change your datatype to text and check to make sure that problem is due to datatype and bind function is not needed as you don't have any parameter which needs to be bind. If your query contains "?" then you need to bind value of that parameter. In your case you already have date and journeyID. Let me know what happen after you change your date column datatype to text.

Comment: Even it not get update after changing the datatype datetime to text

Comment: Are you getting Record Added alertview after update or log for save error ?

Comment: @Shima let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1450/discussion-between-deeps-and-shima)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use updateStatement not compiledStatement